# Como encontrar um src específico de imagem dentro da página via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, query, image

Fala galera, tudo bom ?

Estou tentando escanear os elementos(imagens) de uma página na web, para encontrar um src específico, porém não estou conseguindo tratar o elemento img/src.

Alguém sabe como proceder ?

Ex: a página possui várias imagens da class: fog-image, porém possuem src diferentes, e queria encontrar na página imagens com um src específico

```
<div class="fog-image">
    <img class="fog-image-img" src="images/colors/red/5.png">
</div>
```

A página possui várias imagens da class fog-image, com src variados, ex:

```
<div class="fog-image">
    <img class="fog-image-img" src="images/colors/red/5.png">
</div>
<div class="fog-image">
    <img class="fog-image-img" src="images/colors/red/2.png">
</div>
<div class="fog-image">
    <img class="fog-image-img" src="images/colors/yellow/5.png">
</div>
<div class="fog-image">
    <img class="fog-image-img" src="images/colors/blue/5.png">
</div>
```

Eu gostaria de verificar via javascript se a página em questão possui alguma imagem como src=".../2.png" ou src=".../5.png", e caso encontrasse me emitisse um alerta, como posso solucionar isto ?

Não precisa ser somente o ..blue/2.png ou o ..red/2.png, mas sim todas as imagens de nome /2.png e /5.png se possível, para que não tenha que tratar todas as cores

Tentei utilizando:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("img[src='../2.png']");
```

porém não deu certo, sabem como posso tratar este problema ?

Muito obrigado desde já

Edit:

```
const c = async (index) => {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll("img[src*='/2.png']");
    numItems = items.lenght;

    window.alert(numItems);
    window.alert(items);

};
```

numItems esta printando "undefined"

Items está printando [object NodeList]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando digito

```
document.querySelectorAll("img[src*='/2.png']");
```

O Console me mostra a NodeList(4) [img.fog-image-img...] com 4 elementos, porém não consigo verificar o tamanho para comparar se é maior que 0

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132692/discussion-on-question-by-rafael-lopes-como-encontrar-um-src-especifico-de-image)